# Passando string para time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Estou pegando 2 strings no formato **hh:mm:ss** para então calcular o tempo passado entre elas no formato dias, horas, minutos e segundos.

Já fiz o split e tenho os campos todos separados em suas próprias variáveis do tipo inteiro, por exemplo: `hora_inicio, minuto_inicio`, etc. Porém, estou tendo problema para as conversões minutos x horas, segundos x minutos, etc.

Tem alguma maneira de eu "montar" uma variável do tipo time com essas minhas variáveis `hora_inicio, minuto_inicio` para então ficar mais fácil o cálculo do tempo passado?

Comment: Como você vai calcular o intervalo em dias se as strings só falam sobre horas, minutos e segundos?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida os dias são enviados diretamente por outro input

Comment: Você só quer saber como criar `datetime`s para essas horas?

Comment: exato. Quero saber como usar o hh para compor o referente à hora, o mm ao campo referente aios segundos, etc.

Comment: Como observação, você não precisa fazer um split; basta usar o `datetime.strptime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a classe [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) do pacote datetime pra criar uma data com informação de hora:

```
from datetime import datetime

dataComHora1 = datetime(2018, 1, 29, 22, 35, 12)
```

Você pode fazer operações matemáticas em objetos `datetime`. Como você quer a diferença entre duas datas, use a subtração:

```
diferenca = dataComHora2 - dataComHora1
```

Com esse objeto resultante, que é do tipo [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), você pode extrair as informações que deseja (`seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `total_seconds` etc.)